# Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '': fs.js (1728:7)

Tags: react-native, expo

[image: Image of error]

I don't know how this happened, I accidentally added a typo in a package and when I removed it, this happened. I believe it has something to do with my package.json.

This is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "student-management",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "date-fns": "*",
    "expo": "^44.0.4",
    "expo-app-auth": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~12.1.3",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-speech": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.0",
    "moment": "*",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-calendars": "*",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "*",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "*",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-time-picker": "*",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "4.3.1",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid making changes to the node modules - it's only causing you trouble down the road :-)

To clean the modules run `rm -rf node_modules` and afterwards `npm install` again to reinstall the node modules.

I hope it fixes your issue!

Comment: @VaweSomE perfect, I'm glad. Please consider to accept my answer then :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try `expo start -c`
to clean your cache. The excess cache can mess up some installations